# How to convert cvShowImage into java method using opencv

Tags: java, opencv

I want write this one in java. But some of things are cant write in java .This is my c function using  opencv

```
   include “highgui.h”
   int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
   IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );
   cvNamedWindow( “Example1”, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   cvShowImage( “Example1”, img );
   cvWaitKey(0);
   cvReleaseImage( &img );
   cvDestroyWindow( “Example1” );
    }
```

this the way how I am trying to do in java .But cvShowImage,cvWaitKey,cvReleaseImage 
and cvDestroyWindow cant write in sameway, I don't know how to convert into those function into java even I try google it.It didn't feel better.this is my java class

```
     import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
     import java.io.File;

     import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

     import org.opencv.core.Core;
     import org.opencv.highgui.*;

     public class displayImage {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
         System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
          File input = new File("/home/digital_image_processing.jpg");
          BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);
          cvNamedWindow("MyImage",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
          cvShowImage("MyImage",image);
          cvWaitKey(0);
          cvReleaseImage(image);
          cvDestroyWindow("MyImage");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
 }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no gui support for the java api, so you can't open a (native) window.

you will have to [resort to java](http://answers.opencv.org/question/31505/how-load-and-display-images-with-java-using-opencv/), make a BufferedImage from the mat, and display it on a frame or canvas.